# PermitRootLogin = no but no other sudo users

Tags: debian, root, sudo

I'am using Debian Jessie.

I changed PermitRootLogin from yes to no in this file /etc/ssh/sshd_config , I saved but I forgot to create another super user account !! Now I'am logout and I can't access to my server as a Sudo because I can't edit this file from my other account :(

Help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you login via SSH as a normal user then do `su root` it will allow you to change user to root user.

You will of course need your root password. then add a new sudo user or whatever, you will have full root access.